# Adding a filter to a table on my webpage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, .net-3.5, dynamic-data

Simple problem. I use the Entity framework to map an SQL Server database to objects. The EF is then used to fill a Dynamic Data Site. There are 50+ tables and layout isn't really important. Allowing the users to use it for quick data entry while keeping the amount of code as low as possible is.
Basically, I have four work-hours to find a solution to filter some of the tables on the first letter of one (or more) of the fields. (One filter per field.) When I have one, I have another 4 hours to implement it. Any time I spend more on this will not be compensated. :-(

I have full control over the code, the database structure and whatever else. However, I am limited to .NET 3.5/Visual Studio 2008 and am not allowed to include MVC. I'm also not allowed to add more libraries. Can't upgrade to .NET 4.0 either. So, how can I add such filters in a minimum number of hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : add filters the way the Dynamic Data samples add filters, using user controls and FilterRepeaters and designating your custom filters in Metadata .  See the DynamicData/Filterss directory for examples.

For example, in metadata

```
[FilterUIHint("LastNameSearch")]
public object LastName { get; set; }
```

and a user control called LastNameSearch.ascx.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.dynamicfilter.aspx) link on MSDN

Comment: @Wim, If I recall correctly, yes. Check here : http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/14475